# Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, fatal-error, memory-limit, memory-size

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /vqmod/vqcache/vq2-storage_modification_system_engine_action.php on line 69
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /system/library/session.php on line 81

Event memory limit is sufficient it is throwing above error.
Any solution welcome!
Thank you

Comment: Are you using core php or any frameworks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution on my website.

In my admin folder, I have a php.ini file

I have changed my

```
memory_limit = 64M;
```

to

```
memory_limit = 128M;
```

### Note

You have to change the php.ini file on line 18 memory_limit = 64M; to
64 x 2 = 128 or 64 x 4 = 256 but wait to ask your hosting provider do
they support higher limit size if yes then it will work otherwise you
are wasting your energy.

Now it works fine.. I didn't get Fatal Error.

Comment: Thank you but I found the solution and something else was causing the issue.

Comment: Okay great. I will always help for needed people's.