# Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 268439552 bytes)

Tags: php, html, domparser

```
$html = file_get_html('https://m.gsmarena.com/');
$videos = [];
foreach ($html->find('div.swiper-half-slide') as $video) {
foreach ($video->find('strong')as $name){

   echo $name->innertext;
   $videos[]=$name;
}}
print_r($videos);
```

im getting fatalerror Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 268439552 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\scrappingpractise\scraper.php on line 24

Comment: Did you even search for an answer before posting?

Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)

Answer (score 1):

You are running out of memory, by default PHP allows you to allocate 256mb for each execution. You can change it in your `php.ini` file, the option it's called `memory_limit`

Comment: i have changed memory limit to 1000M but still not working

Comment: Have you tried restarting your apache server? You have to do that every time you change something in the php.ini file